# Show special roles on user profile

Tags: 7, entities, users

I have a little issue on drupal 7. I want a **little object/field on the userprofile**. This object/field shoud **show special roles** of the user (special = "admin, moderator ...").
And is it possible that this object comes directly after the username ?

(I am very sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works for me.

Modules used:

- Display Suit
- Display Suit Extra
- PHP filter
  (I hope I didn´t forget one)

Here is how I did it ...

1.Go to a Profil

2.Click on "Edit"

3.Switch to the tab "Manage display" (right upper corner of the overlay)

4.scroll down to "custom fields" and click it

5.click "Add a code field"

6.check "User" on *"Entities"* and change the Text format in the *"Field code"* to "PHP code"

7.Now type the following in the "Field code" (Add/Change the Roles You have)

```
<?php $account = user_load(arg(1));?>
<div class="user-roles">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($account->roles as $role): ?>
            <?php if($role != "authenticated user"): ?>
<?php //--------------HERE YOU NEED TO ADD/CHANGE THE ROLES YOU HAVE------------------- ?>
                    <li class="user-role- <?php 
                    if($role == '[Your Role]'){ echo 'user-role-[your role]'; }
                    elseif($role == '[Your Role]'){ echo 'user-role-[your role]'; }
                    elseif($role == '[Your Role]'){ echo 'user-role-[your role]'; }?>">
<?php //------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ?>
                    <?php print $role; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

8. Press "Save"

That´s it. I hope it works for You too.

(Again I apologize for my bad English. It can gladly edit for correcting my grammar)

Comment: good you find the solution on your own :)